# How to perform statistical test of significance in deep learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, statistical-significance

I was reading the paper ["Practical Recommendations for Gradient-Based Training of Deep Architectures" by Bengio](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.5533), and at page 10 there is this footnote:

> we should use a statistical test of significance and accept a new
>   minimum (over a longer training period) only if the improvement is
>   statistically significant, based on the size and variance estimates
>   one can compute for the validation set

The paper is about how to properly train a neural network. But, how can I perform this type of statistical test of significance?

In particular, suppose that I have split my dataset into training set, validation set and test set. For each epoch, I calculate the accuracy on the validation set, then, what should I do next?